# Providing feedback on copy / paste functionality

Tags: error-message, error-prevention

I'm working on a set of applications, one of which is a JS based web app, and the other of which is a desktop standalone application.

Due to security issues, browsers won't allow users to copy to their clipboard to paste to or from the web application. Instead users have to 'copy as' and select a particular filetype to copy before being able to copy and paste to the other application.

I was wondering what peoples' thoughts are regarding the best way to let users know that they need to 'copy as' instead of using the command c to copy between applications. Feedback from users has shown that they aren't generally aware of this, and I need a simple way to let them know.

Other team members aren't keen on modal windows, but I can't see many other options to let users know.

Any help / input would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you pushed back on that security requirement? If you can avoid designing for a sub-optimal experience that is probably easiest...

Comment: Yep - unfortunately there's no real way around it. I would certainly like to avoid, but it's not feasible in this instance.

Comment: IIRC there is an exact question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a tooltip to inform user the recommended course of action. Medium has a good example. It pops up a tooltip whenever the user highlight a word or paragraph.

[image]

Using the same idea, you could show a tooltip to guide the user to use "copy as" instead of hotkeys. This is based on the assumption that the user wants to do a copy and paste every time they highlight over a bunch text.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZKH3D.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat unusual so I'd be as explicit as possible and have a button to "copy as" next to a drop down box to select the filetype (format). The "copy as" button would be disabled until a copyable selection is made. There would be a format initially selected in the drop down, and that would suggest there are other formats available.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsnLCG.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

(As an aside, even if you disable the easy conventional ways of copying things in the browser, I question whether you can really stop a determined person from getting hold the selected data and doing what they want with it. If it's visible in the browser, I believe I can get it with dev tools or something - I don't think there's any way around that.)